# From column when sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

The answer should be easy, but I couldn't fine.

I am sending email in asp.net using c#. I want to change the `From` part of the email to something meaningful instead of the email address. For example instead of `123@website.com` I want the user to see `website.com support team`.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();                    
message.From = new MailAddress("support@website.com");                   
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(this.txtEmail.Text));
message.Subject = "Welcome to Website";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
message.From = new MailAddress("support@website.com", "website.com support team");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
message.From = new MailAddress("Support Team support@website.com");
```

Everything that is before space will be treated as description, and after last space will be address. It also works with `To` property.